# Добавление строк в таблицу через админку wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть страница [тык](http://rl66.ru/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-apple/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82-iphone-%D0%B2-%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5/). Шаблон самописный, посажен на wp. Нужно реализовать добавление строк в таблицы посредством админ панели wp. Проблема в том, что таблиц много, каждая будет содержать свой контент. Делать кучу custom fields, либо делать custom post types, либо есть какие-то плагины/способы? Важно сохранить стили и структуру таблиц.

Вид заполненной таблицы. [image: таблица]

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте попробовал плагин [TablePress](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/screenshots/), он как раз делает именно то, что вы описали без лишних заморочек